# scandir в подключаемом скрипте

Tags: php, файловая-система

index.php

```
<?
include("/nn/nn.php");
?>
```

/nn/nn.php

```
<?
$nndir = scandir('new');
?>
```

Директория '/nn/new' существует и содержит файлы. С правами проблем нет.

Не работает. Как правильно юзать scandir в подключаемом скрипте?

`__DIR__` не вариант, потому что не хочу светить файловую структуру сервера

Answer (score 0):

Решено:
в nn.php

```
$nndir = scandir(basename(__DIR__).'/new');
```